# How to Convert Type in Tuples

Tags: haskell

how to convert a String type to a Int

i have a tuple and i want to convert it to a tuple which has different types

```
tupletotuple :: (String,String,String) ->(String,Int,Int)
tupletotuple (a,b,c) = (a,read(b),read(c))
```

i get this Error Msg

```
Project> tupletotuple ("cha",4,3)
ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num [Char]
*** Expression : tupletotuple ("cha",4,3)
```

Comment: Try `tupletotuple ("cha","4","3")` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a tuple of 3 strings to convert.  The result will be a string and 2 ints.